# Drag select rows in TListview

Tags: delphi, listview, drag

I am trying to figure out a way to select rows in a `TListview` by dragging over them (like dragging a window over icons in Windows Explorer to select them). This is not about drag and drop, only dragging.

I don't think I need an action on `MouseDown` since that row is already selected when I click, but I think I need something like:

```
OnMouseMove check if X,Y is above a row
If so, change its IsSelected to true
If not, do nothing
I don't know if anything is needed on MouseUp
```

The question is, how can I check if the mouse x.y is within/above a Listview row?

Comment: Why not just use the MultiSelect property?

Comment: So what is the problem then? With MultiSelect on you can select any/all rows in the TListView at once using mouse selection dragging.

Comment: there must be some other property conflicting with that. MultiSelect = True, I am using a vsReport ViewStyle, RowSelect = True, with GridLines. I've deleted the Listview and created it again, with the same result.

Comment: Given these details( which you should have specified in the question) I can perform a multi-select just fine, what Delphi version are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GetItemAt` method of `TListView` (and maybe also `TListView.GetHitTestInfoAt`).

Comment: That seems to be it, i'm going to ask a separate question because the MouseMove event can't seem to tell if the mouse button is down or not. But thanks for this solution.

Comment: @ikathegreat  LeftButtonDown := (ssLeft in Shift)